# Git without complete local copy

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-push, git-remote

Say I have a largish repo on GitHub, and I'm pushing from a computer with a very small amount of space. I'd like to push files one by one without having to keep every file from the remote. If I wanted to edit a file from the remote, I'd download it, make my changes, and then push back up to the remote. Is there any way to do this?

I want to do this *programmatically* for a web service.

Comment: Are you aware you can edit files directly on github.com? No checkout needed.

Comment: @DanLowe Yeah. I want to do something *just like this* but programmatically. It's for a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to implement this using GitHub's API.

You can retrieve the content of a file given the path:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents

> This method returns the contents of a file or directory in a repository.
>
> `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`
>
> Files and symlinks support a custom media type for retrieving the raw content or rendered HTML (when supported). All content types support a custom media type to ensure the content is returned in a consistent object format.

And you can also update the content at a given path:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file

> This method updates a file in a repository
>
> `PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`

You can also create new files, or delete files.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#delete-a-file

The API is extensive - you can find much more in the documentation.

Comment: Also, thanks for the edit to my question. Now I realize it wasn't quite clear ;)

Comment: You might want to mention the "Creating a file" section of that document as well.

Comment: @LukeTaylor added that.